# Does the Code-First approach in Entity Framework always create an Id field even if HasKey is used to identify the primary key?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a One-to-One relationship in Entity Framework Core 2.2 in which I identify the primary keys in both entities using Fluent API `HasKey()`. When I add a migration and update the Sql Server database the identified primary keys get created along with an Id column. Does the Id column always get created even though it doesn't actually hold any data or am I missing something?

Profile.cs

```cs
public class Profile : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    protected Profile() {}
}
```

Profile DbContext Configuration

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Profile> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(p => p.ProfileId);

    builder.Property(o => o.ProfileId)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .IsRequired();

    builder.HasOne<Person>(p => p.Person)
        .WithOne(s => s.Profile)
        .HasForeignKey<Person>(s => s.ProfileId);
}
```

Person.cs

```cs
public class Person : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Address MailingAddress { get; private set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }

    protected Person() { }
}
```

Person DbContext Configuration

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(p => p.UserId);

    builder.Property(p => p.UserId)
        .ValueGeneratedNever();

    builder.Property(p => p.FirstName)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50);

    builder.Property(p => p.LastName)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50);

    builder.Property(p => p.DateOfBirth)
        .IsRequired();

    builder.OwnsOne(p => p.MailingAddress);

    builder.Property(p => p.MobilePhone)
        .HasMaxLength(20);
}
```

Migration Results

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Profile",
        columns: table => new
        {
            ProfileId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
            Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Profile", x => x.ProfileId);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Test",
        columns: table => new
        {
            TestId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
            Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Test", x => x.TestId);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Person",
        columns: table => new
        {
            UserId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            FirstName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
            LastName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
            DateOfBirth = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
            MailingAddress_Street1 = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            MailingAddress_Street2 = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            MailingAddress_City = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            MailingAddress_State = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            MailingAddress_Country = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            MailingAddress_ZipCode = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            MobilePhone = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 20, nullable: true),
            ProfileId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Person", x => x.UserId);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Person_Profile_ProfileId",
                column: x => x.ProfileId,
                principalTable: "Profile",
                principalColumn: "ProfileId",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_Person_ProfileId",
        table: "Person",
        column: "ProfileId",
        unique: true);
}
```

I expected the `HasKey()` syntax to take precedent over the Id field and the Id field not to be created.

Comment: EF does not create automatically `Id` column (or any other column except for FKs). Most likely your base `Entity` class not shown here contains something like `public int Id { get; set; }`

Comment: @IvanStoev that was it! Thanks!